# Find sides of a right triangle given hypotenuse c and area A (no numbers given)

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, area

I've solved couple of these, but I have no idea how to solve it without any numbers provided. I've tried using $A=\frac{ab}{2} \Rightarrow 2A=ab \Rightarrow 4A^2=a^2b^2$ and incorporating $b^2=c^2-a^2$, but I don't know what to do next...

$$c^2=a^2+b^2$$ $$b^2=c^2-a^2$$

Then we proceed as:

$$A=\frac{ab}{2}$$
$$2A=ab$$
$$4A^2=a^2b^2$$
$$4A^2=a^2(c^2-a^2)$$
$$4A^2=a^2c^2-a^4$$
$$a^4-a^2c^2+4A^2=0$$
... what do I do next?

Comment: **HINT**: Substitute $b^2=c^2-a^2$ into the first equation you found $4A^2=a^2b^2$ and then solve the resulting quadratic equation in $a^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already noted $A = \frac{ab}{2} $ and $a^2+b^2 = c^2$. Now note $ab = 2A$ and $$(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2 = c^2+4A$$

$$\Rightarrow a+b = \sqrt{c^2+4A}$$

Can you go from here?

Comment: Not exactly sure if I understand that (a+b)^2 part. What am I supposed to do with that square? @Daniel

Comment: We know $(a+b)^2 = a^2+b^2+2ab$ and from your information, we know $ab$ and $a^2+b^2$. So we can get an expression for $a+b$ in terms of what is known (this is shown in the last line). From here, we can write $$a = \sqrt{c^2+4A}-b$$ and substitute that into one of the other equation involving $a$ and $b$.